# Como pegar o notificationCode da URL de notificação do Pagseguro?

Tags: node.js, express.js

Nos detalhes da notificação tenho:

Os seguintes parâmetros foram enviados via POST:

notificationType=transaction

notificationCode=D666218281808180F60334A66F8340B434F9

```
{
  "request": {
    "url": "https://brunoiglesias.eng.br/notification",
    "parameters": {
      "notificationType": "transaction",
      "notificationCode": "D666218281808180F60334A66F8340B434F9"
    },
    "headers": {},
    "method": "POST"
  },
....
```

Na minha API NodeJS tenho a seguinte rota:

```
routes.post('/notification', PagSeguro.notification);
```

Com a seguinte função:

```
    notification(request, response){
        console.log("notificação de mudança de status");
        console.log("request");
        console.log(request.parameters);
        console.log("request body");
        console.log(request.body);
        console.log("request query");
        console.log(request.query);
        console.log("request params");
        console.log(request.params);
        return response.status(200).json({});
    }
```

Porém tenho como saída o log:

```
Feb 05 22:18:13   {}
Feb 05 22:18:13   request params
Feb 05 22:18:13   {}
Feb 05 22:18:13   request query
Feb 05 22:18:13   {}
Feb 05 22:18:13   request body
Feb 05 22:18:13   undefined
Feb 05 22:18:13   request
Feb 05 22:18:13   notificação de mudança de status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você terá de usar o [body-parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) para ler o `body` de uma requisição `POST`

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```